# CryptoAPI function 'CryptAcquireContext' failed. Error 0x8: Not enough storage is available to process this command

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, storage, sql-server-2000

I get this error in my production website while the C# code tries to open a SQL connection object.  I found this by debugging the code.

The production SQL server version is MS SQL 2000.
The app server version is Windows server 2008.

There are enough storage available in both the app server and the database server.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: post the error message and code

Comment: CryptoAPI function 'CryptAcquireContext' failed. Error 0x8: Not enough storage is available to process this command

I have already mentioned it in the title :(